# UIImagePickerController ios 5 issue when select the image uising UIPopoverController in ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, uiimagepickercontroller

i have the problem with the select the image from UIImagePickerController in ipad in ios 5.
same code was run perfectly in ios 4 .

so what is the problem ?
can any one help me how to use UIImagePickerController in ios 5 ?
Is there any difference between ios 4 and ios 5 for UIImagePickerController ?

Below is the code for the issue.

```
-(IBAction)selectExitingPicture:(id)sender
{

    if ([popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        [popoverController release];
    } else {
        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
             UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
        {
            UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
            [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            imagePicker.delegate = self;
            imagePicker.sourceType =
            UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                      (NSString *) kUTTypeImage,
                                      nil];
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;

            popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                      initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];

            popoverController.delegate = self;


            [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(280, 700, 320, 400) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];

            [imagePicker release];

        }
    }

}


-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:true];


    NSString *mediaType = [info
                           objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {

    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        selectedImageView.image = image;

    }
    else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
    {
        // Code here to support video if enabled
    }
}
```

After selecting the image from UIImagePicker in the imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method i received the image reference 0*0

Thanks

Comment: You'd need to ask this under Apple's Dev Forum's not here since its NDA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
       -(IBAction)buttonpressed{ 
        UIImagePickerController *anImagePickerController = [UIImagePickerController new];
        anImagePickerController.delegate = self;
        anImagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

        UIImageView *anImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"overlay_320x427.png"]];
        anImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 1, 320, 427);
        anImageView.hidden = YES;
        anImagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = anImageView;

        [self presentModalViewController:anImagePickerController animated:YES];
        [anImagePickerController release];

        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(timerFireMethod:)
                                       userInfo:anImageView
                                        repeats:NO];
        [anImageView release];
    }
    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {




 /* Do something here*/
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];




    }

    - (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```