# iOS 5 : UIImagePickerController crash

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5, uiimagepickercontroller

I am facing problem with the `UIImagePickerController` in iOS 5.

My App was developed in `iOS4.3` but now I am upgrading it to `iOS5`.

My App crashes when I try to select Image from Photo Library.

It is crashing in main.m file with `EXE_BAD_ACCESS` and does not giving any crash logs.

I am using following code for `UIImagePickerController` to pick image from photo library.

```
-(IBAction) photoLibraryAction {
    if ([self isPad]) {

    UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]; 
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary; 
    picker.delegate = self; 

    UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
    self.popoverController = popover; 
    //[popover release];
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(btnLibraryPic.frame.origin.x, btnLibraryPic.frame.origin.y, btnLibraryPic.frame.size.width, btnLibraryPic.frame.size.height) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];


    //[picker release];
}else {
    ipc=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    ipc.delegate=self;

    ipc.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentModalViewController:ipc animated:YES];
} 
}


 #pragma mark - Image Picker Delegate
 -(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
  {
 [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 [picker release];
  }



-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo :(NSDictionary *)info
{   

imgV.image =[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

if ([self isPad]) {
    [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}

[[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

[picker release];   

 }
```

I have searched on SO and I found many links [like1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810251/uiimagepickercontroller-crash-on-ios-5), [like2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368831/about-the-api-of-uiimagepickercontroller-in-ios-5), [like3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222288/uiimagepickercontroller-in-uipopovercontroller-is-not-opening-up-in-ios-5), [like4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704998/uiimagepickercontroller-ios-5-issue-when-select-the-image-uising-uipopovercontro)
 and [like5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677058/uiimagepickercontroller-crash-in-ipad-ios5).

But none of this contain any proper solution.

What should I do ?

Comment: Maybe start by describing the problem. What goes wrong? What is the crash log?

Comment: are you using ARC now?  I noticed *some* of your `release` calls are commented out.

Comment: @PengOne : I am not getting any crash log it shows "EXE_BAD_EXCESS" in main.h. My Code works fine with the iOS4.3.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann : No I am not using ARC.

Comment: @Devang: (1) update the question with relevant information. (2) on what line is it crashing? (3) what is the exact error message?

Comment: @PengOne : Check updated question. Hope it will be useful to solve my problem.

Comment: I am suspicious of the last line in your snippet above where you call `[picker release];`

Comment: I have already tried after removing [picker release] but still it crashes.

Comment: Is it crashing on iPhone or iPad?  Both?

Comment: Try changing `[[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` to `[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`.

Comment: @zpasternack : YES crashes on both

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```